# Parse JSON using flatMap() in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following json structure in cells in a Google Sheet:

```
[{"value":"example1@example.com","isPrimary":true},{"value":"example2@example.com","isPrimary":false}]
```

What I want to achieve is that I have all values and isPrimary flags in separate columns, i.e.:

```
example1@example.com | true | example2@example.com | false
```

Google Apps Script using the following did not work:

```
const SAMPLE = value => [JSON.parse(value).result.flatMap((...))];
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot undertand the logic for retrieving `example1.example.com - true - example2.example.com - true` from `[{"value":"example1@example.com","isPrimary":true},{"value":"example2@example.com","isPrimary":false}]`. In your situation you want to change `true` to `false`? And also, I cannot understand `What I want to achieve is that I have all values and isPrimary flags in separate columns`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Your English is great, no worries. I made a slight edit on the question, too. What I need is the 2 values in cells next to each other. This is technically the same as the answer you gave to the question "Parse JSON using Regex in Google Sheet" here in StackOverflow - I just cannot adapt your solution there to my problem. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided, I see you're using a custom function. In your Apps Script file enter the following and save changes:

```
const SAMPLE = val => [JSON.parse(val).flatMap(({value, isPrimary}) => [value, isPrimary])];
```

In your sheet enter the following formula (change A1 to the cell where you have the JSON data):

`=sample(A1)`

Here is an example of the result:
[image]

Comment: Brilliant! This works, thanks so much! I basically had it, but with "value" on both sides of the "equation", not "val" and "value" as you did it. Once again, thanks a lot!